# Opening another tkinter window from one tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter window in the file gui.py. Upon the press of the Spacebar, I want to open another Tkinter window which is used to obtain an input from the user via the file imageinput.py.

So, I wrote the code to execute the run function of imageinput.py

```
def keyPressed(event, data):
    if event.keysym == "space": image_run()
```

When I run this, I get the following error:[image]

What is the best way to open such another Tkinter window this way?

Comment: Use `tk.Toplevel()` to open a second tkinter window. If you want help with your code you'll have to show us a [mcve].

Comment: error shows you have problem with image - it can be common problem with PhotoImage removed from memory by garbage collector - see Note on http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing more of your code, you would create a new "top level" widget and use that widget like you used the original root top level window ( `root = tkinter.Tk()`) as the parent of whatever widget hierarchy you create. So...

```
def image_run(parent, *args, **kwargs):
    top = tkinter.Toplevel(parent)
    top.transient(parent)        
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(top, ...)
    :
    :
```

Hope that helps!